# updateOrInsert without updating the "created_at" column

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I used the following query to update the `last_update` column of a row in my table:

```
DB::table('some_table')
    ->where('last_update', '>=', now()->subMinutes(5))
    ->updateOrInsert([
        'user_id' => 11,
        'comment_type' => 4
    ], [
        'last_update' => now()
    ]);
```

But, now I needed to add the `created_at` column. Also, I need to manually create it in the first insert. Is it possible to modify the above query so that `created_at` will be inserted the first time and won't update anymore? Or am I going to have to use another query?

Comment: im just curious, why dont you use timestamps function in the first place? it will make created_at column which will be midified once in creation, and it will also generate updated_at column which will be modified on edit

Comment: Because in this case, this row can be updated in multiple occasions, this is a specific `last_update` or some event, but not the timestamp `updated_at`. `update_at` in this case can be updated by another event

Comment: well in that case, can't you use timestamps for the created_at, ignore the updated_at and use your last_update column instead?

Comment: I am not sure I can, if I have multiple update columns, like `last_update_event1` and `last_update_event2`. Is it possible to use multiple update timestamps and only update the relevant one per event?

Comment: for the update column you can use your above code, the timestamps is only for the created_at column.

Comment: Oh wait you have a point. I am going to try

Answer (score 0):

you should handle the `created_at` field at the DB level by making it default to current timestamp